# EF5 Has problems deleting an entity. It worked before...Where am I going wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have researched other answers that contain the same errors. So I would thank people not to say this is a duplicate. The other posters apparently are knowingly using multiple contexts. I am not at least knowingly.

Scenario...

I started a standard MVC project, and extracted the models to a model layer. Fully tested, everything worked.

Next I extracted the repository from the controllers. No code was changed except that I made a generic interface and implemented it. Again, it all worked. However I am working toward applying design patterns in MVC and after much reading I wanted to separate my repository into separate classes for the different CRUD operations. Single responsibility principle.

So I made separate interfaces as needed, and began the process of implementing separate repositories based on them. All **except** the delete repository works.

Literally all that happened is the code dbset.remove was taken out of the controller, and put into a repo layer which contains only a single method. Delete. Here is my code.

Controller:

```
    ReadOneRepository<Course> readOneRepo = new ReadOneRepository<Course>(new SchoolDemoEntity());
    DeleteRepository<Course> deleteRepo = new DeleteRepository<Course>(new SchoolDemoEntity());

    // GET: /Course/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Course course = readOneRepo.Read(id);

        if (course == null) return HttpNotFound();

        return View(course);
    }

    // POST: /Course/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Course course = readOneRepo.Read(id);
        deleteRepo.Delete(course);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Repo Interface:

```
namespace SchoolDemo.Repository.Interface
{
    public interface IDeleteRepository<TEntity>
    {
        int Delete(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

Repo Implementation of above interface: - Starting with base class which is common to all CRUD repos:

using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace SchoolDemo.Repository
{
    public class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
        protected readonly DbContext dbContext;

        public BaseRepository() { }

        public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
            dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the repository...Which inherits the base class and implements the interface:

```
using SchoolDemo.Repository.Interface;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SchoolDemo.Repository
{
    public class DeleteRepository<TEntity>
        : BaseRepository<TEntity>
        , IDeleteRepository<TEntity>
          where TEntity : class
    {

        public DeleteRepository(DbContext dbContext) 
            : base(dbContext) { }

        public int Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            //**** THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART ****

            dbSet.Remove(entity);
            return dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The important part marked above is the code that has been extracted directly from the controller, and from the old repo when everything was part of the base repo class. It all worked then.

However now I get the following error:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager.

After reading other questions I tried adding the following line below the important comment...

```
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
```

To which EF now replies with:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

On researching this error I get some very complicated answers however they don't seem to apply to my situation as mentioned, I am not using multiple contexts that I am aware of. Also I am trying to delete, where others are trying to save or do some other functionality. If anyone answering looks at similar questions and can understand how they apply to my situation, I'd appreciate an explanation of how to do it. But, excuse me for saying this so bluntly, I mean no disrespect, they seem a bit convoluted for a simple generic delete repo, especially considering every other operation works. Im thinking I must have made some typo or simple logical error.

As I am using a generic repository I also have a separate set of code for the student controller which uses the same repository...So I will post this encase it gives any clues.

Student Controller:

```
    ReadOneRepository<Student> readOneRepo = new ReadOneRepository<Student>(new SchoolDemoEntity());
    DeleteRepository<Student> deleteRepo = new DeleteRepository<Student>(new SchoolDemoEntity());

    // GET: /Student/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Student student = readOneRepo.Read(id);

        if (student == null) return HttpNotFound();

        return View(student);
    }

    // POST: /Student/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Student student = readOneRepo.Read(id);
        deleteRepo.Delete(student);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I get the same errors for student. And so the same question applies. I have debugged and verified that the readOneRepo.Read(id) method is actually returning the proper record.

If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate the help...

Comment: the objects are coming from different context instances, so you can't read the object from one context and delete it from another. you should alter your repository pattern so that you can read / write / delete from the same context.

Comment: @DLeh - Can you explain how. I taught by inheriting the base class which initialises the repo, I was using the same one. thanks for your help.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Thank you john for your help with this.

Comment: You really shouldn't be making database calls inside of a MVC controller. MVC controllers are meant to be thin route drivers. You should have actual business logic class responsible for this https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/never-mind-the-controller,-here-is-the-orchestrator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't separate actions into different repositories. You should have one repository that does all CRUD operations, and shares a context instance between these methods.

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    protected readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public BaseRepository() { }

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    // read, update, delete methods here that all use the same dbContext instance
    public int Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
        return dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Read(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        return dbContext.Table<TEntity>().Where(filter); //Not sure what the generic method is to get a table in EF, but it's something like this
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I had it before...(and of course it worked) but what about separation of concerns. Is a read, not  a separate concern than a write, or delete or update?

Comment: No, those are all the same concern: database operations on the given entity.

Comment: Well in this case, I guess I got a bit overzealous with my patterns! :) I should put it back together. Thanks.

Comment: yes. Anything that is communicating directly with the database is the same concern. You will never have a setup where you read an object from one database and delete that object from another database.

Comment: I was going to ask how come the update works as I taught I was reading the record to update first. But I am not...Seems only delete does this. Thanks for your help...I will reassemble my repo back together and accept this as the answer. +1 on everything...

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted and am very grateful to DLeh for his answer. I think this is the right way to go in most cases. However, after recombining all my repos as suggested there so I only have one repo, I remember why I did this in the first place. It was so I could add cross cutting concerns easily where needed such as:

- Testing (I can test each part of the repo separately using TDD/BDD)
- Caching reads, (as caching generally only applies to reads).
- Pooling writes, (as pooling and transactions generally only apply to writes).
- Logging, (generally you only want to log changes).
- Validation.
- Error handling.
- Security etc.

I wanted to be able to do this on an "As Needed" basis instead of blanketing my whole repo and forcing everything to use it weather it needs it or not. So I will suggest and alternative solution that I figured out after applying a few more brain cells.

Im not saying this is right, its just an alternative to the far more complicated answers I read on the mentioned errors...And it may or may not work for the other questions I have read. But it fits my needs perfectly.

If you have structured your code like mine into separate repos, because of separation of concerns. There is a way around the multiple context errors as follows:

I recall that I had a ReadOne Repo that looked like this:

Interface:

```
namespace SchoolDemo.Repository.Interface
{
    public interface IReadOneRepository<TEntity>
    {
        TEntity Read(int id);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
using SchoolDemo.Repository.Interface;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SchoolDemo.Repository
{
    public class ReadOneRepository<TEntity>
        : BaseRepository<TEntity>
        , IReadOneRepository<TEntity>
          where TEntity : class
    {
        //public ReadOneRepository() : base() { }

        public ReadOneRepository(DbContext dbContext)
            : base(dbContext) { }

        public TEntity Read(int id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }
    }
}
```

It inherits from the base class, so I choose to change my delete repo, to inherit from it as it needed the read functionality...like this:

```
using SchoolDemo.Repository.Interface;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SchoolDemo.Repository
{
    public class DeleteRepository<TEntity>
        : ReadOneRepository<TEntity>        //This was the 1st little change made, changed from BaseRepo
        , IDeleteRepository<TEntity>
          where TEntity : class
    {

        public DeleteRepository(DbContext dbContext) 
            : base(dbContext) { }

        public int Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
            return dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can use the following successfully in my delete controller:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Student student = deleteRepo.Read(id); //Here is the 2nd change (from ReadOneRepo.Read() to the inherited deleteRepo.Read()).
        deleteRepo.Delete(student);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

By doing this, it forced the single context without any complicated coding to detect if attached and attaching if not ect.

Concerns...

Liskov substitution principle is not violated as the delete subclass can still do what its base class ReadOneRepo can do. It just extends the existing functionality by adding delete as needed.

Single responsibility principle is not violated as it does not contain directly another implementation of Read. It inherits it. Still leaving a single place to go (back to the Read base class if code needs changing).

Open / Close principle can now be satisfied as I can extend either or both classes without affecting the delete class as if I extend the readOne to accommodate caching for example, I can do so in a separate line of inheritance satisfying the OCP.

I don't think I am violating the I (as my classes don't have any direct dependencies apart from inheritance on the base, so IOC can be used easily) or D (I think it satisfies D as none of my repos are using interfaces they do not need) of the other SOLID principles. Not sure about other design pattern or best practices if any are being violated. I would love to hear opinions on it.

As for me this seems to be a very elegant solution which allows me to keep every CRUD operation separate (if needed) and still overcome the problem posed which is to eliminate the errors without using complicated coding solutions. Only 2 lines of code changed and nothing added.

I hope this helps others but I wanted to add it for myself as mentioned in many other SO questions, I used SO as a reference for myself also so if I have this problem again, I know where to come to fix it.

Thanks again everyone for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Why go through the dog and pony show of those interfaces? Just mark your methods virtual. You do not actually vary the implementation so those interfaces are just fluff.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - Not sure I understand. Still learning design patterns (I guess I always will be as they are always changing). But if the implementation doesn't change, what is the benefit of marking them virtual too. Why not just forget both interfaces and virtual methods? (that's a honest (not rhetorical) question as I would like to learn). For me I was thinking...down the road I could use the interfaces for DI/IOC purposes. Also the implementations may vary if for example I decide to add threading, or caching etc.

Comment: Marking the methods virtual leaves them open to extension. The most obvious extension point is inside an integration test so you can return static data. You don't need interfaces for IOC containers, IOC containers are more than happy to instantiate concrete objects. There's actually a huge benefit to using concrete objects with IOC containers, it requires no configuration.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - You make some cool points that I have not really taught of before. Can you offer a link or two to some resources to support this so I may research your perspective. Its very interesting. I was with the perspective that without interfaces the code is tightly coupled. Especially given most design patterns use interfaces mostly to reduce coupling. I was also with the perspective (perhaps wrong considering yours), that interfaces are needed for DI/IOC.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete the entire class BaseRepository<TEntity>

`DbContext` is already a generic repository. It's silly to wrap an already generic repository in another generic repository for no purpose.

If you truly have code that needs reused, such as entity auditing information (createdby, updatedby stuff) you can **inject** `GenericRepository<T>`. While it seems I'm being pedantic, I am not. The major difference is use of delegation instead of inheritance.

C# does not allow multiple inheritance so you can never group `BaseRepository<City>` and `BaseRepository<State>` together. To group these together, you would have to implement a **fourth repository** that encapuslates those 2. How do we get to 4 repositories there? DbContext, City, State, and now CityAndState.

Instead if you **must** have code reuse your repository should look like:

```
public class CityAndStateRepository {

    readonly GenericRepository<City> _cities;
    readonly GenericRepository<States> _states;

    public CityAndStateRepository(GenericRepository<City> cities,
                                  GenericRepository<States> states)
    {
        _cities = cities;
        _states = states;    
    }

    public virtual Tuple<City, State> GetCityState(string city, string state) {

        var city = _cities.DoStuff
        var state = _states.DoStuff

        return new Tuple(city, state)
    }
}
```

Note my usage of tuple is for illustration purposes, I would not recommend creating APIs that routinely return tuples.

And with `GetCityState` marked virtual this class is fully testable in terms of whatever relies on `CityAndStateRepository` for an integration test.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Thanks for your answer, I will study it further as I need a better understanding of these concepts..